# Text not displaying on hover, css

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to get the p element to appear as I hover over the img.  Right now, nothing happens.  The page actually starts with the text visible, which makes me think the transform property is not actually doing anything.  I'm including all of the code for this page.  The header code may not be necessary, but I'm including it in case it is somehow interfering.

I've looked up similar questions on here (one of which I asked) and I can't seem to find the answer.  Tried different browsers - no luck.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #101010;
}

.inner-header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.logo-container h1 {
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.logo-container h1 span {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.navigation {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
}

.navigation a {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.navigation a li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navigation a:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.mission {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.mission p {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: .25s ease-in-out
}

.mission img:hover+.mission p {
  transform: scale(3);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.mission img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Grid2.css">
  <title>Awesome Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner-header">
      <div class="logo-container">
        <h1>MY<span>SITE</span></h1>
      </div>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <a>
          <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <a>
          <li>About</li>
        </a>
        <a>
          <li>Portgolio</li>
        </a>
        <a>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mission">
    <img src="./330px-GABRIEL_VELLA_vs_ROMINHO_51.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus nesciunt ratione animi facilis. Quo, et?</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I expect text to appear as I hover over.  Right now, the text is stagnant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm correct in thinking your aim here is to position the `p` tag over the top of the image, then you can catch the on hover for mission and transform it that way. A codepen example here: https://codepen.io/lewisnewson/pen/BaBdEzB I have added the following code after your current hover statement:

```
.mission:hover p {
  display: block;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lewis.  That worked exactly the way I hoped it would.

Answer (score 0):

You got selector for `p` element wrong. It's not:

> `.mission img:hover+.mission p`

... but:

`.mission img:hover+p`

However as after hover `p` element overflows `img` it's also required to add `pointer-events: none` to `p` so that is won't disappear (as there is no longer hover over `img`).

#### Snippet

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #101010;
}

.inner-header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.logo-container h1 {
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.logo-container h1 span {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.navigation {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
}

.navigation a {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.navigation a li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navigation a:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.mission {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.mission p {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.mission img:hover+p {
  transform: scale(3);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.mission img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Grid2.css">
  <title>Awesome Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner-header">
      <div class="logo-container">
        <h1>MY<span>SITE</span></h1>
      </div>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <a>
          <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <a>
          <li>About</li>
        </a>
        <a>
          <li>Portgolio</li>
        </a>
        <a>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mission">
    <img src="./330px-GABRIEL_VELLA_vs_ROMINHO_51.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus nesciunt ratione animi facilis. Quo, et?</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```